# How to attach a deck ledger board to house joists

Tags: deck

I am replacing an existing deck that uses joists cantilevered from the homes second floor. I'm cutting off the part coming out of the house and plan to attach a ledger board. Code requires some kind of bracket that anchors the deck to those joist ends in the house. It seems like the bracket needs to attach inside the house, but that part of the house isn't easily accessible. Is there a better way to attach the ledger board [image: Ledger-Receiving Joists]?

Note: the cut joists are now flush, and that inch and a half of two by four is removed.

Answer (score 2):

This is a tricky situation....
Normally there would be a rim joist at the edge of your framing which you could attach your ledger to.

This is what I would do for a really beefy construction:

1. Gain access to the inside and install full height blocking between the joists.
2. Install a rim joist on the exterior and connect the blocking to the rim joist so they form one unit.
3. Install hangers or angles to connect the blocking to the joists on the interior.
4. install waterproofing (flashing over the exterior rim joist) to create an continuous waterproofing layer on your exterior wall.
5. Install your ledge board with spacers at the lag bolts to form a gap between the ledge board and flashing of about 1/2"

This construction would accomplish two things:

1. Avoid any attachment into endgrain of your joist. Don't even try this. Screwing into endgrain is weak. That is why we use angles...or even hangers.
2. Create a continuous water proofing layer at your exterior wall
3. Create an air gap between wall and ledger to avoid rot. (This is my personal take. Attaching this way would need to be confirmed with the Building Department)

To properly and legally do this you would get input from a Structural Engineer and a building permit.

Answer (score 0):

I'd look at using standard joist hangers upside-down. Too bad you didn't leave 3" stubs. That would've made attachment easier. With any luck you can slip them in, though you may need to run a recipro-saw alongside the joists to make clearance.

Run any ideas you settle on past the inspection office, though. They have the final say.